# Why all these decimals with sympy.solve?

Tags: python, decimal, sympy, symbols

I have this system to solve:

(*y*-1) *x* = 0
(*x*-1) (1/2-*x*) *y* = 0

I want to use Sympy's `solve`, but it gives me:

```
[(0.0, 0.0), (0.500000000000000, 1.00000000000000), (1.00000000000000, 1.00000000000000)]
```

Why all these decimals? I don't want them! what's wrong?

```
import sympy as sm

x, y = sm.symbols('x, y', negative=False)
X = -x*(1-y)
Y = -y*(1-x)*((1/2)-x)

XEqual = sm.Eq(X, 0)
YEqual = sm.Eq(Y, 0)

equilibria = sm.solve( (XEqual, YEqual), x, y)
print(equilibria)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the expression below

```
...
Y = -y*(1-x)*((1-x-x)/2
...
```

and wonder why the outcome is now *what you want*.

Comment: Using `Y = -y*(1-x)*(sm.Rational(1, 2)-x)` gives you what you want too…